# Django Snippets Install

Tags: django, code-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have downloaded http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1289/ for breadcrumbs, how to configure it in the application ? i.e. where to place the file and any configuration changes ?

Comment: I've found all the snippets are well documented - and google is your friend if not.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely very new to Django, so you may have a bit of reading to catch up on.

The snippet you linked to is basically a tag library. You can read about how to [create and use Django tag libraries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) in the official docs.

For what it's worth, I would put my tag library in a `tags.py` file in a Django app.